# Auto-Pagination for Google Chrome in 2015?

Tags: chrome

The autopagerize chrome extension doesn't work for me and I can't find any alternative solutions.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autopagerize/igiofjhpmpihnifddepnpngfjhkfenbp?hl=en

Does anyone know any other plugins or approaches? It seems that Greasemonkey is no longer a big thing.